# Код определяющий присутствие четных чисел

Tags: c#, консоль

Написал код которая определяет наличие четных чисел в введенном числе и хотел узнать какие присутствуют недочеты. Просьба писать понятным языком. Язык c#

```
string num = Console.ReadLine();
string[] a = num.Split();  
int sum=0;    
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
        int test = (num[i] % 2);
        sum += test;   
    }    
if (sum != num.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("В введенном числе присутствует четное число");
    }
            else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Все числа нечетные");
    }
```

Comment: после первого найденного четного числа - нет смысла продолжать цикл

Comment: @Grundy как то так?  
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
{
    int test = (num[i] % 2);
    if (test == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        sum += test;
    }

Comment: Почти. test и sum вам считать не нужно, лучше сделайте логический флаг, и установите его, если нашли чётное `if (num[i] % 2) {even = true; break};`

Answer (score -2):

```
string numbers = Console.ReadLine() ?? null;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(numbers))
    throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(numbers));

int[] values = numbers.Select(value =>(int)char.GetNumericValue(value)).ToArray();
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", values.Where(value => (value & 0x01) == 0x00)));
```

Вот еще вариант, как просто определить есть ли четное число, понятным языком!!!

```
public bool IsEven(params int[] values)
{
    return values.Any(value => (value & 0x01) == 0x00);
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).